# Accepted design pattern for preventing event handler loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I seem to run into this problem all the time while working with jQuery.  When two form fields A and B have change event handlers that modify the other (A modifies B and B modifies A), what is the accepted design pattern for preventing them from creating a circular loop?

Comment: it really depends on the implementation, but I would set a variable, or hidden input that is set so that the change() event knows that it was programmatically changed, and not a change from the user

Comment: My preference (which can't always be reasonably be done) is to avoid the situation.  For form validation, I tend to have a single function that sets everything up, and anything that needs a change handler uses the same handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're triggering the partner element's "change" handler explicitly from each handler, just set a flag on the source element and abort the handler if you see that flag.

```
function handler(ev) {
  if ($(this).data("handling-now")) return;

  $(this).data("handling-now", true);

  // do stuff

  $(this).data("handling-now", null);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... That would work.  Would you recommend using .data() for this?

Comment: @rinogo ha ha yes sorry I was editing that in ... you could use a class name too if you wanted; it's sort-of just a style preference.

Comment: I would avoid messing with the DOM.  jQuery's `.data()` method just stores the data in a JS variable, yes?  Should be much faster.

Comment: @Brad yes that's a really good point.  You could also do it with a closure variable if the event handlers were set up appropriately.